# What does a "Leave Open" vote do?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

When I vote on a question to "leave open", how does that affect the closure of the question?  Does a "leave open" vote negate a "close" vote, or does it simply do nothing, or does it do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting a "Leave Open" vote in the close review queue, counts towards getting the question out of the queue and kept open.
If any question in the close review queue (CRQ) gets **three** "leave open" votes it gets removed from the queue (thus greatly reducing the chance that it will be closed).

It does **not** negate the close votes, but if the review item is completed with a Leave Open result, the close votes will begin [aging away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away) immediately.

[What exactly happens with the button "Leave Open" (previously "Do Not Close")?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139834/278094)